# Laravel 5: add data to $request->all()

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5, controller

I've been trying to add the id of the current logged-in user into a field in my DB.

But, nothing is stored. I have tried the following methods:

```
 public function store(StoreChildRequest $request)
    {
    $user = Auth::user();
    $child = $request->all();
    $child->merge(['user_id' => $user->id]);
    $child = new Patient($child);
    $child->save();
    }
```

But the StoreChildRequest always returns the user_id is not passed.

Also this didn't work:

```
    public function store(StoreChildRequest $request)
    {
    $user = Auth::user();
    Input::merge(['user_id' => $user->id]);
    $child = new Patient($request->all());
    $child->save();
    }
```

The same error.

Even if I try to do so with fixed data, the merge won't happen:

```
public function store(StoreChildRequest $request)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    Input::merge(['user_id' => "01"]);
    if($child = new Patient($request->all()))
    {
        $child->save();
        return response()->json(['succes' => 'Child saved.']);
    }
    else
    {
        return response()
        ->json($request->getMessageBag()->toArray());
    }

}
```

**EDIT**
I have noticed that when I remove the StoreChildRequest (the validation) the code works just fine. So I'm going to add the rules:

StoreChildRequest:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'givenname' => 'required|max:255',
            'street' => 'required|max:255',
            'streetnumber' => 'required|max:255',
            'city' => 'required|max:255',
            'postalcode' => 'required|digits:4',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'birthdate' => 'required|date',
            'sex' => 'required|max:1',
            'user_id' => 'required'
    ];
}
```

The error has to be in here then?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: dd($user) returns `User` object right ?

Comment: Yes, it does. There is something strange going on. If I don't validate the code using the StoreChildRequest, the code works ... I'm going to add my StoreChildRequest to the question.

Comment: if this request is post,then your $request->all(); has csrf index,and this field is not in your table.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. Because when I remove 'user_id' => 'required' from the StoreChildRequest, the code just works fine too (without caring about the _token).

Comment: You are getting `user_id` in the `post` ?

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
$user = Auth::user();
$child = $request->all();
$child['user_id'] = $user->id;
$child = new Patient($child);
$child->save();
```

Also, you could try:

```
$user = Auth::user();
$request->request->add(['user_id' => $user->id]);
$child = $request->all();
$child = new Patient($child);
$child->save();
```

Comment: This would indeed be correct. But apparently my problem lies in the Request (and not in adding the user_id to the data). Thank you for your answer.